# SCSS calculation with multiple values

Tags: css, sass, mixins

**SCSS**

```
@function space($parent-width, $width...) {
  @return $width + $parent-width;
}
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  padding: space(2px, 25px 40px 50px 60px);
}
```

**Result**

```
.box {
  padding: 25px 40px 50px 60px2px;
}
```

I wanted to create a simple function that execute the below result:

**Expected result**

```
.box {
  padding: 27px 42px 52px 62px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function should be:

```
@function space($parent-width, $width...) {
    $result: ();   
    @for $i from 1 through length($width) {
      $result: append($result, nth($width, $i)+$parent-width);
    }
    @return $result;
}
```

See [live example](http://codepen.io/kaarel/pen/gpaMgj).

Comment: Perfect... but can u modify your code a little? i wanted to use the function like this .box { padding: space(2px, 25px 40px 50px 60px); } I don't want comma between each width... also want if $parent-width is null, add a $base-parent-width with $width. Means if i use like this $base-parent-width: 4px;               .box { padding: space(25px 40px); } my expected CSS should be .box {padding: 29px 40px;}

Comment: For your first concern: if you define width parameter not as an arglist but as a list, you can skip the commas in the function call. I don’t think your second wish can be achieved exactly like that, but you can define default value for parent-width parameter in function signature. [See modified example here](http://codepen.io/kaarel/pen/yNYPjN).